# what is this flowering succulent type plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

The leaves feel little plump and watery. Is this succulent? How do I care for it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *Kalanchoe blossfeldiana*, and they are tender succulents. Care should be taken when watering - let the soil in the pot to dry out a bit before you water so it feels a bit dry to the touch on top, then water well and allow the excess to drain away freely. They like bright light - they will do well in sun, but also just bright daylight. Further care instructions here https://www.growerdirect.com/how-to-care-for-your-kalanchoe-plant

Comment: The link doesn't work. But I will try another source.

Comment: That's weird, its working for me - try this one instead https://www.thespruce.com/growing-kalanchoe-plants-1902982

Comment: The plant has now closed all its flowers? What went wrong?

Comment: Probably nothing - if they faded in colour, they're just finished, that's all. Like most plants, they don;t stay in flower long

Comment: They are mostly closed.  I will update with a picture tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated the post. The buds are closed and are like this since the plant arrived. Is the plant missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You already know the name of the flower, but for the future, there is an app called PlantNet that helps you find out the name of the plants. It's very good! J[image]ust take a picture of it and upload it to the app. https://identify.plantnet.org/

Comment: It's not a bad app, but useless if you want to know the specific variety of, say, a particular Juniper - all it'll tell you is it's a Juniper